# html5 mp4 video not playing

Tags: html, video

This is my code :

```
 <video width="400" controls >
     <source src="~/Content/Videos/Light Yagami's Lesson On Swimming.mp4" type="video/mp4">


</video>
```

But Video not playing in all browsers. : look at picture
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pmrP4.png)

In folder video exist and playes as expected, it's mp4 format. Why is that happening?

Answer (score 0):

`~` is not a valid path character.

src should contain valid [url](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL#Syntax).
You should give correct path.

Also, you're file path contain spaces which are not allowed. You should [encode](http://www.w3schools.com/TAGS/ref_urlencode.asp) it.

So the filename in path would be:

```
Light%20Yagami's%20Lesson%20On%20Swimming.mp4
```

Comment: I found solution, i am using asp.net mvc wich doesn't support range requests by default

Comment: What are the range requests?

Comment: Range requests load big files from server to web.

Comment: I 've checked such sort of things, rename file to bla.mp4 but still had the problem, when i load it in just html file it worked fine. problem is asp.net mvc

Comment: Okay.. I am glad you figure it out yourself. :)

Answer (score 0):

I found solution, i am using asp.net mvc whichdoesn't support range requests by default

Answer (score 0):

If you're running IIS/.NET

Add a web.config file to the root of the application `web.config` with the following contents

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <configuration>
    <system.webServer>
      <staticContent>
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".mp4" mimeType="application/mp4" />
      </staticContent>
    </system.webServer>
  </configuration>
```